# Geolocation routing in Amazon/Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have a web app hosted on amazon EC2 server. This application can be accessed through different countries say US, UK, China, India etc

My question is does amazon(or any other cloud service provider) cloud hosting provides the facility to host the servers in different countries (under EC2 by default or extra cost needs to be paid
for that) so that content can be served fast from web servers ?

For example if request is coming from china and its served by EC2 server in china it will be
bit faster than if it is served by server in US as request/response has to hop from nation grid/network to international network ?

Comment: You are talking about cross-zone load balancers

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-disable-crosszone-lb.html

If you want static contents you can use amazon cloud front service (makes your S3 a CDN)

Comment: @DanielKrom he's not talking about load balancing at all. He's talking about either geolocation routing, or latency based routing. Also, CloudFront works with more than just S3, and more than just static content. Also it doesn't "make your S3 a CDN". CloudFront is a CDN, which can be placed in front of S3, among other things.

Comment: @MarkByou got it right. Cloudfront is just CDN which forwards the request to best edge location(edge locationcaches the content from data centres to reduce time latency) to save request hopes. Is this the cloudfront that does the geolocation routing ? If yes, do AWS client have to pay explicitly for this ? i believe No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Route53 for DNS then you can use Geolocation based routing. Or since you are mainly concerned with routing to the fastest location (reducing latency) you could Route53's Latency based routing. The different Route53 routing policies are documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html).

I would suggest you first look into the possibility of using a [Content Delivery Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) which can cache your server responses in edge locations all over the world. When a user requests something that is in the CDN cache they will get a response from the closest CDN edge location. This will be faster and cheaper than managing multiple copies of your servers all over the world, as long as you are able to use the cache effectively.

Comment: Thanks Mark. when you say `If you are using Route53 for DNS ...` does not amazon always use Route53 when we take any of AWS cloud computing service like EC2 server ?

For CDN caching, it will work for static content not for dynamic content like search or where inventory is dynamic right ?

Comment: You would have to be using Route53 for a custom domain that you own. You can't go into Route53 and modify route settings if you don't have your own domain being served by Route53. A CDN can absolutely be used for dynamic content, but obviously if the content changes frequently then it can't be cached efficiently.

Comment: @scottmiles, CloudFront will still tend to improve the *performance* of the *transport* of uncached dynamic content, and this effect is most notable when the viewer is more distant from the server.  The reasons for this are somewhat complicated to explain here, involving optimized TCP stacks, keep-alives, connection reuse, pixie dust, a managed edge-to-region transport infrastructure, and automatic/transparent geo-routing to the CloudFront edge node nearest the browser, but... yeah, try it.

Comment: @MarkB `You would have to be using Route53 for a custom domain that you own.`  My question is if i am using amazon web hosting , do i have to tell amazon explicitly that i want to use router 53 or amazon used it for all web hosting  by default? I understand if i am not using amazon web hosting(using some one else web hosting) i need to buy amazon 53 router services for latency/gelocation routing ?

Comment: @scottmiles Route53 is a separate AWS service that you have to start using by setting up your custom domain. I don't know how to make that any clearer. You can't go in there and setup geolocation routing if you aren't using Route53 for your domain's DNS. AWS is using Route53 internally for DNS, but that is irrelevant to your question. You can't tell AWS you want to use geolocation routing in Route53 if you aren't paying for a domain in Route53.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks. Got it. . one last question say when i type myApp.com  in browser and i set up myApp.com using  amazon Route53 . how DNS resultion for myApp actually work. i believe first call goes to amazon DNS service which resolves the myApp.com to its clodfront ip and which further gets the content from edge location . Is that Right ?

Does DNS servers and Route53 servers lies in each country for faster resolution ?

Comment: Yes that's how DNS works. Yes Route53 uses a network of servers around the world. You can see the list of server locations here: https://aws.amazon.com/route53/details/

Comment: @MarkB one more clarification. My company has taken one EC2 server(company has not explicitly asked for Route53 service. atleast IT guy i asked,he was not aware of it) for QA testing(we ahve QA team both in US and India) of my web application and given the URL `http://<ip_address>:<port>/myApp/` to access the web app.  I believe in this case Geolocation routing does not come to picture. Probably my company network is on virtual LAN of amazon where server lies(server must be lying either in US or india ). Is that right ? If that's the case, it will be comparatively slow for one of the QA team ?

Comment: If you aren't using Route53 with geolocation routing configured, then you aren't using geolocation routing...

Comment: So  company must be on virtual LAN of amazon where server lies(server must be lying either in US or india ). Is that right ? If that's the case, it will be comparatively slow for the QA team in  one of the country ?

Comment: I have no idea what "virtual LAN of amazon where server lies" means. Are you trying to say the EC2 server is in the AWS VPC? That is **always** true. And I don't see how that has any relation to the question about using Route53 Geolocation routing. If you aren't using Route53 then you aren't using it. End of story.

Comment: thanks for using the word VPC. Yes that what i meant. I will post separate question for second part.